# My Gnome 3 in Ubuntu 11.10 is not showing any applications in applications menu?

Tags: gnome

My Gnome 3 in Ubuntu 11.10 is not showing any applications in applications menu. It is presenting blank menu and showing no applications. What should I do to recover my application shortcuts in applications menu of Gnome.

Comment: What happens when you right-click the Application menu on your gnome-panel? Can you 'edit menu'? Is there a list of applications to tick / untick?

Answer (score 1):

[Manik Rastogi](https://askubuntu.com/users/69675/manik-rastogi) solved the problem in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156656/my-gnome-3-in-ubuntu-11-10-is-not-showing-any-applications-in-applications-menu#comment200079_156665):

> I have found the solution. I opened 'Applications Menu' program which is used to custumize applications menu and selected all applications that were displayed by default. Now my Gnome applications menu is as good as it was.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me sometimes as well. But when I start typing my application name in the *"Search Applications"* area it keep start showing all the apps.

Comment: i tried that but it is also not working since i've installed some gnome extensions. I think there might be some problem with that. Can any please help me resolve that ?

Comment: I have found the solution. I opened 'Applications Menu' program which is used to custumize  applications menu and selected all applications that were displayed by default. Now my Gnome applications menu is as good as it was.